# is there an official doc planning how to create a module

Tags: magento2, module, documentation

I've spent several hours reading magento 2's official documentation, and I haven't found how to create a module :

- The documentation explain the structure of the filesystem, list the files that we can create in some directories (for example [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/build.html)),
- The exprected content of the composer.json module.xml and registration.php are well explained (several times),
- I've found some informations about the possibles entries in the configuration files (app/etc/*.xml),
- **But** I've didn't found a comprehensive explanation of all the content of the files (controller, view, layout, model, setup, ...).
  Did I missed something or all this area isn't covered by the doc?

the best ressource found untill now is this one : [Creating a Magento admin page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html) (but it do not cover all the need, for example, I want to learn how to add an "array" of custom data about the customer)

**edit** : I add what I try to do in order to show that it is not covered by the doc : 
*add an "array" of custom data to the customer thoses data will permit to buy or not the products*

- How to add thoses custom data :  **not covered** (I think that I need to alter the data model to add new tables, in the setup file of the module)
- How to request thoses data in the frontend :  **not covered**
- How to view/edit those data in the admin :  **not covered**
- How to let the customer edit thoses data :  **not covered**
- How to create REST API (wich will permit thoses data to be populated by a remote system) :  **not covered**

Comment: for now, I've found thoses external ressources wich I will uses if I don't find anythinf official : 
 ,  https://aionhill.com/magento-2-module-development-part1
 ,  https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-introduction/
,  https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-create-a-magento-2-extension/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Create a module" is kind of broad as there is different types of modules. Fortunately, Magento 2 team provides a github repository with module samples: https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples

On top of that I suggest you check out the amazing Alan Storm article: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/

Comment: I mean, I didn't find any words of the expected/possible content of so many files (for example the controller and the block aren't covered at all), I dive in your links now on!

Comment: thanks, this link permit to learn several apsects not covered by magento's doc. : http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/

Comment: @bruno feel free to mark your question as answered if you managed to learn what you needed